Image not loading in e-mail after renaming jobs in Laravel
So, I have a Laravel app that sends out e-mails using jobs/queues. It worked great, but I updated the names of the mailable/jobs so that it would make more sense. But after that, images in the mails are not loading anymore:

It's simply not loading the url part in the image of the rendered e-mail:
<img align="center" border="0" alt="Image" title="Image" style="outline:none;text-decoration:none;clear:both;display:inline-block!important;border:none;height:auto;float:none;width:26%;max-width:150.8px" width="150.8">
Job SendEventEmailRegisteredParticipant.php:
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Mail\EventEmailRegisteredParticipant;
use Mail;
use DB;
use App\Models\NotificationHistory;

class SendEventEmailRegisteredParticipant implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;
    public $id;
    protected $subject;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct($data, $id, $subject)
        {
            $this->data = $data;
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->subject = $subject;
        }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $notification = NotificationHistory::find($this->id);




        $notification = NotificationHistory::find($this->id);
                $email = new EventEmailRegisteredParticipant($this->data, $this->subject);
                $emailBody = $email->render();
                $notification->update([
                    'sent_date_and_time' => now(),
                    'message' => $emailBody
                ]);
                Mail::to($this->data['email'])->send($email);
    }
}

Mail EventEmailRegisteredParticipant.php:
<?php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class EventEmailRegisteredParticipant extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;
    public $emailBody; // Define the emailBody property

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct($data, $subject)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->subject = $subject; // Assign the subject
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        return $this->view('emails.EventEmailRegisteredParticipant')
                            ->with(['data' => $this->data])
                            ->subject($this->subject); // Use the dynamic subject
    }

    /**
     * Override the send method to capture email body before sending
     */
    public function send($mailer)
    {
        $this->emailBody = $this->render(); // Capture the rendered email content
        parent::send($mailer); // Call the parent send method to send the email
    }
}


Blade EventEmailRegisteredParticipant.php (only relevant part):
<table style="font-family:'Cabin',sans-serif;" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="overflow-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-word;padding:40px 10px 10px;font-family:'Cabin',sans-serif;" align="left">

                              <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" align="center">
                                    <img align="center" border="0" src="{{ asset('assets/img/de_zeekat_trans.png') }}" alt="Image" title="Image" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: inline-block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;width: 26%;max-width: 150.8px;"
                                      width="150.8" />

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>

                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>

I have another job, that was not renamed, and that works perfectly, with roughly the same code.
Reverting the changes solves the issue.

is the email template file called EventEmailRegisteredParticipant.php ? does it need the .blade.php instead?

There may be a reason for not loading the image:

Check the entered correct image path: {{ asset('assets/img/de_zeekat_trans.png') }}

Put the above image in a public path

Clear the cache:
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan cache:clear




Please don't use code-formatting for things that aren't code.
